# CakePHP 3 `setEntityClass()` for a contained table

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0, model-associations, contain

### What I have

- CakePHP 3.6
- `PostsTable` `belongsTo` `AuthorsTable`

### What I want

1. Select posts containing their authors
2. In one specific case, **use a custom entity for authors**

### What I've tried

Googled a lot, couldn't find anything. Had to improvise.

```
// in my controller action:
// set custom class for authors
$authorsTable->setEntityClass('App\Model\Entity\AuthorCustom');
// get authors
$results = $authorsTable->find('all');
```

That works fine.

```
// in my controller action:
// set custom class for authors
$authorsTable->setEntityClass('App\Model\Entity\AuthorCustom');
// get products including categories
$results = $postsTable->find('all')->contain($authorsTable);
```

That doesn't work because `contain()` doesn't accept a table instance.

Does anyone know a way to set a different entity on just one `find()` call?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do that in the first place? What's the problem that this is going to solve?

Comment: @ndm I need the entity to behave differently when I'm preparing it for a Google API endpoint. I did not want to clutter the main entity with that logic, so thought about using a separate entity just for this

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `contain()` accepts an array|string|null and you are trying to pass it a `Table` instance. Pass it the table name instead used for hydration:

```
// in my controller action:
// set custom class for authors
$authorsTable->setEntityClass('App\Model\Entity\AuthorCustom');
// get products including categories
$results = $postsTable->find('all')->contain($authorsTable->getTable());
```